# Horizontal menu in Safari

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm going a bit mental trying to figure this out.
I have a horizontal menu that works fine in every browser except Safari.
In Safari the last menu item is pushed down to the next line.
It's the main nav on this page
http://www.allsafety.co.uk/

I've tried loads of different things, and now I've just myself in a right pickle.
Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Not just Safari, broken in Chrome 24/Mac as well.I suspect all webkit browsers will have the same issue. Menu is too wide for the container. You're asking a lot for someone to weed through 5 CSS pages to find relevant code.

Comment: i can't find the problem i check in all browser ???

Comment: Works on the Windows WebKit browsers, so it's just Mac then?
Sorry @Skaught, 5 CSS pages? I don't get what you mean with that.

Comment: I see links to 5 .. no 6... separate style sheets at your link. Post the relevant code, don't make others do the work to find the appropriate CSS and HTML.

Comment: Actually it's also broken in Chrome on Linux ;) If you change the padding of `nav ul li a`(in [style.css](http://www.allsafety.co.uk/wp-content/themes/OGJigoTheme/style.css) to `8px 16px 8px 15px`, it looks fine. I guess the problem could be in the way fonts are rendered on different browsers/OS. Safari in general renders fonts bolder than the rest of the browsers, just like OS X usually has bolder fonts.

Comment: What?
Have you never used Firebug or any other browser dev tools?
The number of stylesheets is utterly irrelevant. Just inspect the element, and hey presto, it tells the you the relevant style sheet and line number.

Comment: Thanks @NikolaIvanovNikolov. I think you might be right there. I think there is about a px or two difference, which is an issue as when hovering over the Contact link there is a px on the right that does not change color in the hover state. Honestly, why can't they all just behave in the same way?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, they don't :/ I know that feeling, you can probably do a hacky jQuery fix for that if this is critical, since I can't think of a plain CSS solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to fix similar problem(in my case though the problem is that the navigation labels can change, and that would break the layout, since the padding is initially set, so that all elements fit precisely in one line).

Like I said in my comment above, JS is probably the most-reliable solution in this case, so here is the code for that:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        _fix_nav_width();
    })

    $(window).load(function(){
        _fix_nav_width();
    })

    function _fix_nav_width() {
        var w = 0,
            max_w = $('.menu-main-nav-container').innerWidth(),
            length = $('#menu-main-nav > li').length,
            diff = 0,
            padd = 0;

        $('#menu-main-nav > li > a').each(function(){
            w += $(this).width(); // Get width without padding
        });
        diff = max_w - w; // Calculate the space that we should padd
        padd = ( diff / length ) / 2; // Calculate the amount of padding we should add on each side of the li's
        $('#menu-main-nav > li > a').css( { 'padding-left': padd, 'padding-right': padd } );
    }
})(jQuery)
```

We fire the function twice - on `$(document).ready()` and on `$(window).load()` - you might see flashes of improper layout for a second, but IMO that's the best way to do it(since usually the element's fonts are not rendered yet on `$(document).ready()`).

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers treat **CSS** `letter-spacing` / kerning differently. It looks as though it is being pushed down because this is slightly bigger than the width of the horizontal bar. On moments like this, even slight rendering differences in how font-sizes are handled can affect the outcome.

I would try messing with certain font styles such as:

```
font-size
letter-spacing
word-spacing
```

You could instead just remove padding from the last right tab.

**CSS**:

```
#menu-main-nav > li:last-child > a { padding-right: 0; }
```

Or, with **jQuery**:

```
$('#menu-main-nav > li:last-child > a').css( { 'padding-right': 0 });
```

Hope that helps?